# Derivative of singular convolution integral

Tags: derivatives, convolution, singular-integrals

While trying to solve a heat conduction problem, I stumbled upon a kind of equation which, in general form, can be written as:

\begin{equation}
f(t) = \int_0^t \frac{g(x)}{\sqrt{\tau(t)-\tau(x)}}dx
\end{equation}

In the problem I am considering, this equation is coupled to others where the derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ appears.
Therefore I tried to evaluate such derivative using Leibniz's integral rule ([see link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)). The result I obtained is:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f(t)}{\partial t} = \frac{g(t)}{\sqrt{\tau(t)-\tau(t)}}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial \tau(t)}{\partial t}\int_0^t\frac{g(x)}{(\tau(t)-\tau(x))\sqrt{\tau(t)-\tau(x)}}dx
\end{equation}
The integrand on the RHS still has a vertical asymptote at $x=t$, but I am not too worried about it (it is likely the integral converges).

However, the first terms is infinite, which make sense since it is just the evaluation of the integrand in $f(t)$ at $x=t$, i.e. where the function does not exist.

I must assume that Leibniz's integral rule is applicable only if the integrand is continuous in the entire interval of integration, including the boundaries.
This would mean that I cannot perform the derivative with wrt $t$ of $f(t)$ by standard methods.

I was wondering if a derivative of such kind of equation is just mathematically unfeasible or if there are more sophisticated techniques to approach the problem.

Cheers.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this? Add them in question.

Comment: @ArjunRana I edited my question including some context, hopefully my problem will be a bit clearer now. Cheers.